# Need help to change value when time is between two hours

Tags: php

I've tried for a while now, to have some text changed when the time is between two times, and I can't seem to get it working. I have a table, and when the time is between i.e. 14-17, some text should be green instead of black. How would I do this in PHP? I have also given the different `<td>`'s different ID's, for when which one is going to be green.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" width="9%" align="center">Tid</th>
      <th scope="col" width="7%">Rom</th>
      <th scope="col">Band</th>
      <th scope="col">Navn på ansvarlig</th>
      <th scope="col">Telefonnummer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">11-14</th>
      <td>#1</td>
      <td id="1-1">Band 1</td>
      <td>Navn på ansvarlig</td>
      <td>+47 123 45 678</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">14-17</th>
      <td id="1-2">#1</td>
      <td>Band 2</td>
      <td>Navn på ansvarlig</td>
      <td>+47 123 45 678</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">17-20</th>
      <td id="1-3">#1</td>
      <td>Band 3</td>
      <td>Navn på ansvarlig</td>
      <td>+47 123 45 678</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">20-23</th>
      <td id="1-4">#1</td>
      <td>Band 4</td>
      <td>Navn på ansvarlig</td>
      <td>+47 123 45 678</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code that creates the table? Just use an `if()` statement to add a class to the element, and then use CSS to make that class green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating table from the php you can do,

```
if (date('H.i') >= 14.00 && date('H.i') <= 17.00) {

  $color = 'green';

} else {

  $color = 'black';
}
```

and create table like,

```
echo '<td style="color:'.$color.';"><td>';
```